# Azure Subfolder Blog

Tags: iis-7, azure, blogs, blogengine.net

I'm trying to figure how how/if it's possible to add a blog to a subfolder on an existing azure site.

BlogEngine seems like it would be a good choice since it's written in .net and from what I've read easy to setup as a standalone site on azure.

The problem I'm running into now is how can I setup my sub folder /blog as an application in azure. I know locally you can just pull up IIS and rightclick -> convert to application. But is there something I could put in the web.config or publish settings that would achieve the same thing?

Right now I'm getting an error message because /blog has it's own web.config file.

If there's an easier way or I'm thinking about this wrong let me know that too :-)

Thanks,
Andrew

**EDIT**

I contacted azure supported and they suggested I upgrade from a azure web site to a azure VM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this time there isn't a good way to run a full fledged blog engine side by side with an azure website without setting up a VM.

I ended up pulling from a google blogger blog using their data API. Not exactly what I was wanting to due but I couldn't take on the extra cost associated with a VM solution.