# Adding Other Projects(Blog Engine) inside an existing MVC5 Azure WebApp

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure-web-app-service, blogengine.net

I am trying to add BlogEngine.NET(web) to my existing MVC5 project (which is running as an azure website) partly based on these [instructions](http://dnbe.net/docs/post/installation). I have downloaded/extracted the entire web project folder and included it as a folder to my existing MVC Project.

My controller has the below code

```
public ActionResult Blog()
{
   var path = Server.MapPath("~/BlogEngine/default");
    return View(path);
}
```

But, I receive the error:

> ....BlogEngine\default' or its master was not found or no view engine
>   supports the searched locations.

by reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25209990/the-view-index-or-its-master-was-not-found), I understand why this error occurs. I just want some pointers on how to add the Blog engine to my existing project.

**EDIT:**

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13281583/azure-subfolder-blog) is exactly what I want to achieve, but azure is not helping(the whole point of me choosing to use azure websites instead of AzureVMs is to shy away from the responsibility of keeping that VM up and running), so looking at the other options at hand, like tweaking my MVC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- goto manage.windowsazure.com
- select the webapp
- Navigate to the Configuration Tab
- Scroll Down to Virtual Applications and Directories
- Add the Path of the Directory there and Select the Application checkbox.
- Hit Save.

[image]